# Second Difference in Unit Root Test

Tags: time-series, unit-root, granger-causality, vector-error-correction-model

If variables are stationary at second difference. Is it possible to proceed to next test with variables stationary at second difference or need to transform the variables to make them stationary at first difference then can proceed to next test? I'll be using cointergration test to test the long run relationship then to VECM followed by Granger Causality test .

Comment: Economic variables rarely are I(2). Are you sure there two unit roots? Maybe there are structural breaks or something similar that makes your unit root tests underpowered?